# Lag/lead variables

Tags: regression, time-series, fixed-effects-model, predictor, dependent-variable

I have a simple question related to the variables in a time series analysis.

I am using a panel fixed effect regression to see the impact of instrument issuance on firm performance. My independent variable of interest is a firm issue dummy (1 = issue; 0 = not issue). In the first regression, I use year $t$ for all variables to see the effect. But I would like to the see the impact of issuance on firm performance one year after issuance.

In this case, is it right to lag the independent variable? Or, should I lead the dependent variable by one year? And, if I lead the dependent variable, should I also lead my independent variables, except the variable of interest (Dummy)?

Answer (score 0):

You should not both lag the independent variable and lead the dependent variable. In your case, assuming I understand your question correctly, it seems you may have want to lag just the dependent variable so that you can see the effect of $x_{t-1}$ on $y_t$.

Comment: Dear Ariel. thanks for you answer. for example  my idea is to see what happen in firm Y in 2018 when firm issue this instrument in year 2017.  I hope that you understand me what I mean now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Ihab, I think this is consistent with my understanding. In that case some form of model with a lagged variable should work, i.e. $Y_t = \beta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ or .$Y_t = \beta X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$  depending on if the dependent variable is also the outcome.

Comment: Hi Ariel, thanks again . please, the first equation ( idea)  looks  very interested. But please let me explain what I got from you. Do you mean that if I  run regression when  the dependent V and Independent V the same but the former was lagged and add to the regression if X1== 1 will i have what how much Y increased/ decreased after issuance? if not . Do you have and idea to see how Y  how much Y increased/ decreased after issuance and compare it before issuance ? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are interested in the effect that an independent variable has in the previous period on the outcome variable in the current period you may lag the independent period and input this lagged variable into your model.